# Increasing point calculation

Tags: equation-solving

How to calculate the increasing point if known variables are sum of total increase points and the first point.

For example, I have the first number of 1000, and I have 37 points until the last one.
Sum of all points should be 107300.

So I have to calculate what number I need to add to every increasing point.

```
Example:

1st increasing point: 1000 + 100 = 1100
2nd increasing point: 1100 + 100 = 1200
...
37th increasing point: = 4600 + 100 = 4700
```

I need to know how to calculate this increasing number (100), as I only know the sum of all points is 107300 and the first point is 1000.

Comment: that gives me result ≈150

Answer (score 1):

You can get an equation for your "increasing number" with

```
Sum[1000 + u n, {n, 37}]
```

> `37000 + 703 u`

Then you can solve for `u`.

```
Solve[37000 + 703 u == 107300, u][[1, 1, 2]]
```

> `100`

Note: But really, `Solve` is overkill for such a simple equation. By inspection it is clear that

```
u == (107300 - 37000)/703
```

which is 100.